# How to use TimePicker to DatePicker MVC3 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, datepicker, timepicker

I'm struggling to understand how to combine the TimePicker http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ solution to my existing ASP.Net MVC3 C# site that uses DatePicker. DatePicker is currently working fine on it's own, but I need to add the time as well as the date, and TimePicker looks perfect for what I need, only I'm not sure how to implement it.

I see the example gives this code:

```
$('#example1').datetimepicker();
```

but I am unsure how to work it into my existing site / DatePicker function.

I have made sure I include these JS files in the HEAD section on the _Layout page, as well as adding the CSS to my existing DatePicker CSS file (jquery-ui-1.7.3.custom.css):

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.7.3.custom.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and on my View page I have this code which displays the input and calls the DatePicker function (this works fine in its current form):

```
@model test.Models.News
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.News_Date)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.News_Date, "News_Date", new { @ID = "News_Date" })
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#News_Date").datepicker({
            showOptions: { speed: 'fast' },
            changeMonth: false,
            changeYear: false,
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            gotoCurrent: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am unsure how to install the TimePicker function so it works with DatePicker on my MVC3 site.

I'd appreciate an explanation if someone wouldn't mind?

Many thanks.

Comment: not working for me can you please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14299219/datetimepicker-jquery-not-working-in-mvc3#comment19861700_14299219

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You simply replace your `datepicker` call with `datetimepicker` in the view and provide the necessary arguments for both:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#News_Date').datetimepicker({
            // Arguments for the date picker
            showOptions: { speed: 'fast' },
            changeMonth: false,
            changeYear: false,
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            gotoCurrent: true,

            // Arguments for the time picker    
            showSecond: true,
            timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss',
            stepHour: 2,
            stepMinute: 10,
            stepSecond: 10
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Darin - sometimes the simplest things escape me, but at least now I know :-)

Comment: Hello there, I am looking at the same stuff with MS SQL - did you ever run into null dates showing as 31-12-1899? With the usual jQuery UI datepicker, it shows me a nice blank date, but with this datetimepicker combo my null dates are showing up as populated..